# Form validate combine input fields at once codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

Is there away to validate many form input fields at once. for example input 1 + input 2 + input 3 will be combined and then validated at once.

heres my view code:

```
<input id="ads_phone1" type="text" style="width:40px" name="ads_phone" maxlength="4" value="<?php echo set_value('ads_phone', $phoneseg[0]); ?>"  /> -
<input id="ads_phone2" type="text" style="width:30px" name="ads_phone" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo set_value('ads_phone', $phoneseg[1]); ?>"  /> -
<input id="ads_phone3" type="text" style="width:60px" name="ads_phone" maxlength="6" value="<?php echo set_value('ads_phone', $phoneseg[2]); ?>"  />
```

here my controller code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('ads_phone', 'Ad Phone', 'required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[20]');
```

i want them to be combine like this ads_phone = ads_phone1 . "-" . ads_phone2 . "-" . ads_phone3;

and then ads_phone will be validated as required.

thanks guys i hope ive explained it well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

```
$ads_phone= $this->input->post('ads_phone1')
          . $this->input->post('ads_phone2')
          . $this->input->post('ads_phone3');

$this->form_validation->set_rules($ads_phone,'Phone', 'required');
```